# Position an HTML element (fixed) on top of another element, not overlapping, with constant spacing on window resize

Tags: html, css, electron

I have a div element, which has a background image that is centred on it. I want an h2 or p element to be positioned, (fixed or absolutely, am not sure which one is correct) on top of that div element, but not overlapping it. It should have the same bottom margin even when the window is resized. I have already tried putting an **innerText** inside of the div with the background image. I added the image like this:

```
<div>    
<!-- other elements -->
   <div class="v-container visible default background-image">
</div>
```

and in css:

```
.v-container {
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: cursive;
}

.default {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.103);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.background-image {
    background-image: url('../graphics/Note.png');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why did you tag your question with Electron?

Comment: I tagged it Electron because I am developing an Electron js app using HTML, CSS and Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I tried for some time to solve my problem and I think I have gotten an answer to my question. Well, it is not exactly the answer I need but it gave the element above the image a constant spacing between the image and the top of its parent container. I achieved this using the `top: x%` and `bottom: -x%` CSS attribute. Where `x` represents the desired percentage. For example, `top: 15%` and `bottom: -15%` achieved the same thing. Am not sure why I had to use the '-' sign while using the `bottom` attribute, but it works. Sample code below of how I achieved this:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>NoteBook 2.0</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/photon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/main.css">
    <script src="../UI/renderer.js" async defer></script>
</head>

<body>    
     <div class="invisible default v-container">
        <h4>Tap a note on the left to view here</h4>
        <h5>Or Tap the&nbsp;
            <span class="icon icon-book"></span> &nbsp;icon at the left to add new note
        </h5>
        <img src="../graphics/Hand_note.png" alt="Note icon">
     </div>

</body>

</html>
```

The stylesheet (CSS)

```
html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
}
    
.v-container {
        background-color: #e9e9e9;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .v-container :first-child {
        position: relative;
        top: 15%;
    }
    
    .v-container :nth-child(2) {
        position: relative;
        top: 15%;
    }
    
    .v-container :last-child {
        position: relative;
        top: 20%;
    }
```

And the result:

[image]

From the image, it appears normal, but when you resize the window, the image still maintains a constant spacing with other elements. The text on top always stays 15% on its parent element because its `position` was set to `relative`. The text element below the first element child also has 15% set ( I guess, what it means is that, because the position was set to `relative` also, it still follows the order in which child elements appear in the parent container.

Answer (score -2):

Can you post your code?
If you explicitly used an image as the background of a div then centering the element will be relative to the div itself and likely never really line up with the background image unless the aspect ratio is perfect.

A solution might be to create a nested child div and setup your margins relative to the parent.

Or you could set the image as an element instead of the background, this would make it much easier to reference.

It would be easier to help if I could see your code.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: I could barely understand what @BagelByte said in his, supposed-to-be answer.